# Cross origin resource sharing issue with Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, apache, tomcat, ionic-framework

So I am trying to make http calls from my ionic application to another application running on tomcat apache serve however I think due to CORS issue the calls are not being successful. I followed the instructions on this site http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/ with no luck. I am running the the tomcat apache application on http://localhost/platform/ and the ionic application on localhost:8100 I added this to my ionic.project:

```
{
  "name": "mobile",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/platform",
      "proxyUrl": "http://localhost/platform/",
    }
  ]
}
```

Added this also to my gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('install', ['git-check'], function() {
  return bower.commands.install()
    .on('log', function(data) {
      gutil.log('bower', gutil.colors.cyan(data.id), data.message);
    });
});

gulp.task('git-check', function(done) {
  if (!sh.which('git')) {
    console.log(
      '  ' + gutil.colors.red('Git is not installed.'),
      '\n  Git, the version control system, is required to download Ionic.',
      '\n  Download git here:', gutil.colors.cyan('http://git-scm.com/downloads') + '.',
      '\n  Once git is installed, run \'' + gutil.colors.cyan('gulp install') + '\' again.'
    );
    process.exit(1);
  }
  done();
});
```

I also added this line to my app.js:

```
.constant('appBaseUrl', 'http://localhost:8100/platform')
```

This is the http call I make:

```
$http({
                method: 'post',
                url: appBaseUrl + '/j_spring_security_check',
                params: {
                    'j_username': credentails.username,
                    'j_password': credentails.password
                }
            })
```

However, the console can't GET the loginsuccess.json which is the response to a successful authentication with the backend server on tomcat. Here is the response on the console http://s16.postimg.org/m2ua3kqc5/console.png

I have spent an entire day trying to make this work with no luck. Btw the specifications of proxy and proxypass for http://localhost/platform/ are defined on the httpd.conf file in the apache folder.

Comment: can you try putting 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost ?

Comment: Where should I try that? for all localhost ? or the appBaseUrl? or for proxyUrl?

Comment: Just try it everywhere.

Comment: Any reason as to why that should work?

Comment: Have you tried using the https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en chrome plugin. Works for me

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your port number difference and I bet this will vary from browser to browser. The current browser you are testing on may see localhost:80 and localhost:9000 as two different domains with regard to CORS. Try differentiating the applications by context. This way the browser knows for sure all requests are coming from the same parent context.

**Paren Context**

http://localhost/platform/

**Child Context (Ionic)**

http://localhost/platform/ionic